# catalytic activity of Pd and Pt

Tags: catalysis, hydrogen

what phenomenon takes place during catalytic activity of Pd and Pt during hydrogenation ? 
in some books it is given as absorption,in others adsorption .some say that it is occlusion .
please help me

Comment: Occlusion is same as "surface adsorption". And catalytic hydrogenation is surface phenomenon...

Comment: but Sir, during formation of hydrides by d block elements ,hydrogen occupies intersticial spaces ? (i think so)

Comment: @DVS but the molecules that are being hydrogenated usually can't access the interstitial spaces through a standard surface.